# Compare two files and print matching values without ignoring duplicates

Tags: text-processing

I am trying to comparing two files and obtain the matching values. I tried this command:

```
grep -Fwf file_1.txt file_2.txt > matched_output.txt
```

However, this script **extracts only unique values**.

**File_1.txt**

```
K00012
K00012
K00024
K00024
K00024
K00027
K00027
K00027
K00027
```

**File_2.txt**

```
ko:K00012 UGDH; UDPglucose 6-dehydrogenase
ko:K00024 mdh; malate dehydrogenase
ko:K00027 ME2; malate dehydrogenase (oxaloacetate-decarboxylating)
```

**Expected Output**

```
K00012 ko:K00012 UGDH; UDPglucose 6-dehydrogenase
K00012 ko:K00012 UGDH; UDPglucose 6-dehydrogenase
K00024 ko:K00024 mdh; malate dehydrogenase
K00024 ko:K00024 mdh; malate dehydrogenase
K00024 ko:K00024 mdh; malate dehydrogenase
K00027 ko:K00027 ME2; malate dehydrogenase (oxaloacetate-decarboxylating)
K00027 ko:K00027 ME2; malate dehydrogenase (oxaloacetate-decarboxylating)
K00027 ko:K00027 ME2; malate dehydrogenase (oxaloacetate-decarboxylating)
K00027 ko:K00027 ME2; malate dehydrogenase (oxaloacetate-decarboxylating)
```

Comment: can the 2nd file contain duplicate keys? (e.g. more than one of `ko:K00024`)

Comment: No, 2nd file includes no duplicated entries, (all are unique).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since those `K??????` values are unique in the 2nd file you could use `awk`, reading the 2nd file first and saving each line into an array at index `K??????` then process the 1st file and for each `K??????` that is in array print the value and the corresponding line:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{split($1, a, ":"); u=a[2];b[u]=$0; next}
{if ($0 in b) {print $0, b[$0]}}' File2_.txt File1_.txt
```

---

Alternatively, with `sed` you could turn the 2nd file into a `sed` script and use it to process the 1st file:

```
sed 's|.*:\([^[:blank:]]*\)[[:blank:]].*|/\1/c\\\
\1 &|' File2_.txt | sed -f - File1_.txt
```

This assumes there's only one `:` (after `ko`) and no backslash in 2nd file and that `K??????` can't contain slashes.

Comment: Why not `b[a[2]]=$0` and `…}$0 in b{print $0, b[$0]}'`

Comment: Additionally `FS="[: ]+"` and `b[$2]`

Comment: @Costas - I was just trying to be more explicit; as to `FS="[: ]"` ... yes, if we're certain they're separated by spaces not by tabs; one could also use `u=substr($1, 4)` ... there are many ways to do this

Comment: Sure. Re tabs it's easy to settle by `FS="[[:blank:]:]+"`

Answer (score 1):

```
while read line
do
    grep -q "$line" File_2.txt
    if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]; then
         echo -n "$line "
         grep "$line" File_2.txt
    fi
done < File_1.txt
```

Feel free to Fine tune this script to give much more optimum result

Comment: Think `result=$(grep -F "$line" File_2.txt) ; [ "$result" ] && echo "$line" "$result"` pass *File_2.txt* 1 only once.